# A regular expression to remove RIDICULOUSLY large numbers from a character vector in R

Tags: regex, r

The problem: ridiculously large numbers within elements of a character vector.

```
troublesome_tweets
[1] "Happi Pi Day! Eat a pizza and some blueberry pie a la mode, and then you may calculate: 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751"
[2] "Sick of this yet? ...2847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432 6648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920..."    
[3] "He only did that 939478978398894709409784680708937809648608378964809798369864 x to the Cavs in that one series"                             
[4] "Am I a robot? Yes, affirmative. 0111001001101111011000100110111100100000011000100110111101101111011001110110100101100101"                   
[5] "Lazy rule # 18460826292036391273639018263920273820183737473920383930; You were too lazy to read the whole number .(:"                       
[6] "#thankyoushootusdown I LOVE YOU GUYS <3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"                
[7] "Hvrtujikdsjktrfedwqcvbntrfedsw1123456787654325678876543234567865432456765432345678654214565tredscvbhjutwsdfvghyu. ! How I feel."            
[8] "I want to dock 555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555"                            
[9] "x's to the club wit momz here 0 while gone 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

The current approach: go after each element and use gsub along with a specific regular expression to remove the large number out of a given specific element.

```
clean_individual_tweets <- function(x){
    x <- gsub("[0-9][.][0-9]+", " ", x) 
    x <- gsub("[...][0-9]+", "", x) 
    x <- gsub("[0-9]+[...]", "", x) 
    x <- gsub("[0-9]+[ ][x]", "", x) 
    x <- gsub("[.][ ][0-9]+", " ", x) 
    x <- gsub("[#][ ][0-9]+", " ", x)
    x <- gsub("[<][0-9]+", " ", x) 
    x <- gsub("[a-zA-Z][0-9]+", " ", x) 
    x <- gsub("555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555", " ", x) 
    x <- gsub("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", " ", x)}


cleaned_tweets <- clean_individual_tweets(troublesome_tweets

cleaned_tweets
[1] "Happi Pi Day! Eat a pizza and some blueberry pie a la mode, and then you may calculate:  "
[2] "Sick of this yet? .. .."                                                                  
[3] "He only did that  to the Cavs in that one series"                                         
[4] "Am I a robot? Yes, affirmative "                                                          
[5] "Lazy rule  ; You were too lazy to read the whole number .(:"                              
[6] "#thankyoushootusdown I LOVE YOU GUYS  "                                                   
[7] "Hvrtujikdsjktrfedwqcvbntrfeds tredscvbhjutwsdfvghyu. ! How I feel."                       
[8] "I want to dock  "                                                                         
[9] "x's to the club wit momz here 0 while gone  "
```

The hoped for approach: to have a single regular expression that can remove all these large numbers and others from large character vectors, let's say to replace any number composed of more than 10 digits. I don't want to delete all numbers, that would've been very easy to start with. I want to specifically remove the artifact numbers and keep the non-artifact ones.

Data

```
troublesome_tweets <- c(
  "Happi Pi Day! Eat a pizza and some blueberry pie a la mode, and then you may calculate: 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751"
, "Sick of this yet? ...2847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432 6648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920..."    
, "He only did that 939478978398894709409784680708937809648608378964809798369864 x to the Cavs in that one series"                             
, "Am I a robot? Yes, affirmative. 0111001001101111011000100110111100100000011000100110111101101111011001110110100101100101"                   
, "Lazy rule # 18460826292036391273639018263920273820183737473920383930; You were too lazy to read the whole number .(:"                       
, "#thankyoushootusdown I LOVE YOU GUYS <3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"                
, "Hvrtujikdsjktrfedwqcvbntrfedsw1123456787654325678876543234567865432456765432345678654214565tredscvbhjutwsdfvghyu. ! How I feel."            
, "I want to dock 555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555"                            
, "x's to the club wit momz here 0 while gone 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"                                
)
```

Comment: cleaned_tweets <- clean_individual_tweets(troublesome_tweets) # missing bracket in the code above

Comment: `gsub('\\d{2,}', '', troublesome_tweets)` ? or `'\\d{2,}|\\d+\\.\\d{2,}'` to get rid of the pi decimal

Comment: Or `(?:\\d+\\.)?\\d{2,}`

Comment: Thanks rawr and Thomas. These regular expression will also delete numbers of two or more digits. Refer to Eric's expression below. "[0-9]{10,}" will only delete any number composed of 10 digits or more. Ciao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'at least 10 digits', try following:

```
 gsub("[0-9]{10,}","",troublesome_tweets)

 [1] "Happi Pi Day! Eat a pizza and some blueberry pie a la mode, and then you may calculate: 3."
 [2] "Sick of this yet? ... ..."                                                                 
 [3] "He only did that  x to the Cavs in that one series"                                        
 [4] "Am I a robot? Yes, affirmative. "                                                          
 [5] "Lazy rule # ; You were too lazy to read the whole number .(:"                              
 [6] "#thankyoushootusdown I LOVE YOU GUYS <"                                                    
 [7] "Hvrtujikdsjktrfedwqcvbntrfedswtredscvbhjutwsdfvghyu. ! How I feel."                        
 [8] "I want to dock "                                                                           
 [9] "x's to the club wit momz here 0 while gone "
```